# How to run BCPL under MacOS or Linux

Tags: bcpl

I just googled this question, but what I found is only under windows. Does anyone know how to set up the environment of BCPL under MacOS or Linux?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.nordier.com/ - `compiling and running a range of older BCPL programs on 64-bit and 32-bit Linux and FreeBSD systems`

Answer (score 0):

Martin Richards' website (and it appears BCPL is still under active development, at least as of March 2021, according to the `FILES` file) states that it's platform independent, so that would be the *first* place I'd be looking for info on BCPL.

His website is [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/) with a link to the [more specific page](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emr10/BCPL.html) detailing how to get it going, immediately preceding the sentence:

> This version can be installed easily on most machines running Linux, Windows and MAC OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is to run a VM, such as DEC PDP10 on simh, and use a BCPL implementation on that. Here is my blog article on installing BCPL on TOPS-10 on a simh PDP10 running on Mac https://www.quentin.org.uk/2018/02/25/installing-bcpl/